# Python: How to add/initialize new global vars IN another module?

Tags: python, django, global-variables

I looked up other posts on the topic and I couldn't find my situation exactly. It is in a Django app, although I believe it's purely a (newbie) Python question. Here's my situation:

Let's say I have mymodule.py where I have various constants and common functions, and at some point elsewhere in the program, I will want to add (and initialize) another attribute for mymodule (if it it's not yet been added):

```
import mymodule

class UserView(View):

    # this method always gets called first..
    def get(self, request):

        try:
            # check if attribute exists
            mymodule.user_data;
        except AttributeError:
            # add it if it doesn't
            mymodule.user_data = mymodule.get_user_data()

        # continue on..

    # sometime later, this method is called..
    def post(self, request)
        print(mymodule.user_data)
```

My assumption was that once mymodule.user_data is added, it will persist as a global variable? Even though I do set it in the get() method first, when I try to read it in the post() method later, I get Error: `'module' object has no attribute 'account'`

Does it need to be pre-initialized in mymodule.py, as some empty object? I may not necessarily know what type of object it will be -- how would I do it in Python? (Sorry, coming from JS -- don't shoot!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this. Your proposed solution is very dangerous, as now all users will share the same data. You almost certainly don't want that.

For per-user data shared between requests, you should use the session.

**Edit**

There's no way to know if they are separate processes or not. Your server software (Apache, or whatever) will determine the number of processes to run (based on your settings), and automatically route requests between them. Each process could serve any number of requests before being killed and restarted. So, in all likelihood, two consecutive requests could indeed be served by the same process, in which case the data will indeed collide.

Note that the session data is stored on the server (only a key is stored in the user's cookie), so size shouldn't be a consideration. See the [sessions documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/).

Comment: I discounted using session because 1) the object is too large, and 2) seems more prone to security issues (available in the client, may contain other sensitive data). My problem is that `get_user_data()` hits an external API which takes good 2-3 seconds, so I don't want to do it every time the user returns to their account page. To clarify my understanding of the global scope: If we have two users running the Django app from different clients, aren't those separate 'processes' on the server? Or will they collide in `mymodule.data['user']`? That, obviously, would be very-very bad!

Comment: Ah, will try session then and report back (seem to recall running into Session size limits in a Rails app..)

Answer (score 1):

You should not want to do that.

But it works as "expected": just do

```
mymodule.variable = value
```

anywhere in your code.

So, yes, your example code is setting the variable in the current running program -
but then you hit the part where I said: "you should not want to do that" :-)

Because django, when running with production settings will behave differently than a single-proccess, single-thread python application.

In this case, if the variable is not set in `mymodule` when you try to access it later, it maybe because this access is happening in another process entirely (thus, "global variables"  (actually, in Python we have "module" variables) won't work, since they are set per process).

In this particular case, since you have a function ot retrieve your desired value,and you may be worried that it is an expensive value, you should memoize it - check the documentation on django.utils.functional.memoize  (which will change to django.utils.lru_cache.lru_cache in upcoming versions) - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/  - this way it will be called once per process in your application as it serves from separated processes.

Comment: Thanks! This all sounds overly complex? "Memoize" seems deprecated -- no docs are coming up on the Dev Trunk. To backtrack, maybe I should ask: Is there an easy way to place an object into the 'global scope' in mid-program, that would work in Django? ;)  I suppose I could have a global variable within my UserView instance, although it won't be available to other classes..

Answer (score -1):

My solution (for now):

In the module mymodule.py, I initialized a dictionary: `data = {}`

Then in my `get()` method:

```
if not ('user' in mymodule.data):
     mymodule.data['user'] = mymodule.get_user_data()
```

Subsequently, I'm able to retrieve the `mymodule.data['user']` object in the `post()` method (and presumably elsewhere in my code). Seems to work but please let me know if it's an aberration!

Comment: As per Daniel's reply above, this is NOT the way to handle it. See accepted answer..